# Haskell Lambda Functions

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am new to Haskell and programming in general.
I am trying to write a lambda function that return a value squared

```
(\x  -> x * x)
```

this is the code I have written. When i try to compile I get this error Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell

I have googled it I cannot fund a solution

Comment: You should assign this to a function, for example `square = \x -> x * x`.

Comment: Thanks that works run if I want to print this I used this code

Comment: 'printsquare = putStrLn (square(5))' but I get an error

Comment: because `25` is not a string.

Comment: You convert it t a string with `putStrLn (show (square 5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign this to a identifier, since `\x -> x * x` as program does not make much sense: you define a function, but then you throw that function away.

You thus can implement a function:

```
mysquare :: Num a => a -> a
mysquare = \x -> x * x
```

then you can *call* the function when necessary. We can for example define a `main` with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (show (mysquare 5))
```

and then call `main`:

```
Prelude> main
25
```

Comment: printsquare = putStrLn (show (mysquare 5)) does not print anything to the console ?

Comment: @KLawson: you *defined* a function, you did *not* call that function.

Comment: I am confused because I am new to haskell. I already tried this putStrLn (show (mysquare 5)) I get an 'errorParse error: naked expression at top level
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell'. with the previous code it runs but it doesn't output anything

Comment: @KLawson: you should assign it to the main to start the program at that point, so `main = putStrLn (show (mysquare 5))`, then compile and run the compiled program.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense. And it actually helped to understand how Haskell works a bit better.